# RxSwift conditional binding

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to use a `UISegmentedControl` with `rx.selectedSegmentIndex` to bind to my viewModel actions. In my viewModel I have these properties:

```
let showSomething1: AnyObserver<Void>
let showSomething2: AnyObserver<Void>
let showSomething3: AnyObserver<Void>
```

In my view controller

```
segmentControl.rx.selectedSegmentIndex.....

viewModel.showSomething1 if index 1
viewModel.showSomething2 if index 2
viewModel.showSomething3 if index 3
```

In my `rx.selectedSegmentIndex` i would like to bind to these but depending on the index of the `selectedSegmentIndex`, what is the best way to do this with RxSwift?

I also want to an animation regardless of which index is selected.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```swift
segmentedControl.rx.selectedSegmentIndex.subscribe (onNext: { index in
            doSomethingWith(index)
        })
```